# BeautifulSoup how to find XML tag?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have the following XML:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<nite:root nite:id="ES2002a.topic" 
xmlns:nite="http://nite.sourceforge.net/">
<topic nite:id="ES2002a.topic.vkaraisk.1" other_description="introduction of participants and their roles">
  <nite:pointer role="scenario_topic_type"  href="default-topics.xml#id(top.4)"/>
  <nite:child href="ES2002a.B.words.xml#id(ES2002a.B.words0)..id(ES2002a.B.words71)"/>
  <nite:child href="ES2002a.D.words.xml#id(ES2002a.D.words0)..id(ES2002a.D.words3)"/>
  <nite:child href="ES2002a.A.words.xml#id(ES2002a.A.words0)..id(ES2002a.A.words12)"/>
  <nite:child href="ES2002a.B.words.xml#id(ES2002a.B.words72)..id(ES2002a.B.words73)"/>
  <nite:child href="ES2002a.D.words.xml#id(ES2002a.D.words4)..id(ES2002a.D.words11)"/>
  <nite:child href="ES2002a.C.words.xml#id(ES2002a.C.words0)..id(ES2002a.C.words7)"/>
  <nite:child href="ES2002a.D.words.xml#id(ES2002a.D.words12)..id(ES2002a.D.words13)"/>
</topic>
```

when I run the the following command,

```
[tag.name for tag in soup.find_all()]
```

I get output:

```
['html',
 'body',
 'nite:root',
 'topic',
 'nite:pointer',
 'nite:child',
 'nite:child',
 'topic']
```

however when I try to use the find all function for night:root, night:pointer, night:child. It returns an empty list:

```
soup.find_all("nite:pointer")
```

returns:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further reasearch i foud that

```
soup.find_all({"nite:pointer"})
```

returned what i was looking for